# Secure authentification in Web

Tags: javascript, php, security, authentication, web

I'm using authentification on the web page in the following manner:

User writes his password (only password- they are unique in the database), which is sent to the server as SHA-3. The systems searches for that hash in the database, if founds, writes to the SESSION the name of the user. And the user is redirected to the main page.

Therefore, each time the main page checks the SESSION, and if it's unset, it sends the user to the authentification page.

Is it safe to access the page checking the SESSION value?
Is it possible to create a counterfeit SESSION to access the page?

Comment: "Safe" against what? MitM attacks? No. Casual script kiddies? Maybe. Do you have gaping security flaws in your implementation which we're not seeing from your high-level description? Who knows…?

Comment: Now I'm talking only about storing the username in SESSION, and accessing the page via checking the SESSION

Comment: Is it possible to create a counterfeit SESSION to access the page?

Comment: It might be possible to just brute-force a valid password...

Comment: Only your server can modify the contents of the `$_SESSION` array, that is entirely within your control. Barring any giant snafus in your server-programming, that specific part is pretty safe, yes.

Comment: Brute force for SHA-512 requires several years to break 8 symbol password

Comment: Having said that, session hijacking is another huge topic in itself…

Comment: Use HTTPS . sent to server as sha3 or encrypted on the server as sha3? The first option would be a security problem

Comment: @Jonasw *"Decrypting"* SHA3…?!

Comment: @Sonya Nobody needs to "break" the hash itself, you just need to guess the right hash to send to the server. That arguably can take a while to figure out, and you can throttle the attempts since it's an online attack.

Comment: @deceze Is there another way to do this, without SESSIONS, or it's usually done like this?

Comment: @deceze : oh. Typo.

Comment: @deceze, you can answer this question in 'Answer' form, so I could accept your answer.

Comment: Sessions implemented correctly are fine. If it's feasible to use *stateless REST authentication* (using the HTTP `Authorization` header), you can implement request signing using nonces, which arguably exposes the sensitive password even less. However, that requires your entire client to be written in Javascript, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: And no, I'm not going to answer vague security questions. I am giving my opinion on specific aspects, but whether something is "safe" is too broad to say over the interweb at this level of detail.

Comment: @deceze Your answer gave me another question for thinking: If I send to the server the SHA-3 of the password, someone may catch the hash, and send it to the server to get access. Therefore, it gets vital to use nonces for authentification also. Without nonces, this kind of security would have no sense. Right?

Comment: Well, whatever you send to the server *is* your password, if that can be intercepted, anyone can log in with that value. So, yes, without nonces this is susceptible to replay attacks. ***However***, if somebody is in a position to intercept your server communication to begin with, they're probably a MitM, in which case even nonces won't help that much, since the MitM could manipulate them. The only thing that really helps is HTTPS.

Comment: @deceze Thanks, you helped me a lot. May I ask another question, please? When a user writes correct password, he is redirected to the main page. In the main page there is a Messenger also ( end-to-end encryption ). I'm going to use Diffie-Hellman for key generation, and use the password of a user for generation. However, I don't want to ask the user about the password again. Is there any secure way to send the password from one page to another? without databases, sessions etc.

Comment: May I save the password in coockie, get it in another page as redirected and delete it from coockie?

Comment: If you're doing that heavy client-side calculations, consider a SPA architecture; then there is no "redirecting". Storing passwords locally is pretty terrible in any fashion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend reading the [OWASP Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet) regarding session management.

As HTTP is stateless, sessions need to be implemented by the application. Your approach is not too far off from what is generally done.

Credentials are asked in the front end and sent as POST parameters. It is very important that this connection is protected by SSL/TLS. You cannot hash client-side and send the hash unencrypted, as anybody intercepting that request can read the hash value and simply replay the request to get authenticated.

It sounds like you want to only authenticate the user by the password alone. Do not do this. Always require Username and Password.

Once you get the credentials server side, you can just look for the username and check whether the hashes of the passwords match (you do not want to store plain-text passwords serverside). If the credentials are valid, in the response you set a cookie value for the session id.

The cookie must be secure and htpps only. The session id must be long and random enough not to be guessed. Once the cookie is set, each new client request will send the cookie with the session id. Your app should store current session ids in order to see which user is making the request without having to authenticate again.

Some frameworks do all of this for you. If you have no experience, i STRONGLY recommend using a framework, or at least reading the cheat sheet thoroughly.

Comment: 1. Why don't you suggest to use only password (without login)? There are about 100 users only, the page is in VPS. Is there any security problems? 2. May I generate a nonce, save it in SESSION, and send the password to the server encrypted with that nonce?

Comment: @Sonya The obvious problem is that no two users can have the same password. That's… odd. If you are in charge of managing the passwords (i.e. you just assign random passwords to users), that's not a big issue. If users are able to pick their own passwords, and you need to reject some passwords because "password is already in use"… err, then users can discover other users' passwords this way. Which is bad.

Comment: @Sonya Secondarily, just a single identifier (password) is shorter than two identifiers (username + password), and therefore easier to simply guess. Again, if you're in charge of assigning passwords and you assign specific long random passwords, then this is mitigated. But if users can choose their own passwords, and can choose their own *rather short* passwords, this is a problem.

Comment: @SonyaSeyrios: i don't understand what the scenario with the nonce is. You would create a custom authentication protocol based on client and server side cryptography that you would have to implement on your own. Why don't you just use SSL/TLS and send the credentials over a normal POST request? When the connection is secure (https) this is not an issue. In fact it is the standard way of sending credentials.

Comment: @SonyaSeyrios: the reason i would STRONGLY suggest you do not do that, is for the reasons deceze explained. When a user registers and the app tells that the password already exists, then this would automatically mean that he could log in as another user. Not ideal

Comment: May I configure SSL on my VPS? How?

Comment: @SonyaSeyrios that would depend on VPS, but usually yes. You check the docs of VPS provider if they some managment for that built-in or search the web for your web server and SSL/TLS enabling it. Post another question on appropriate SE site if you need help with that which searching the web and VPS providers docs can't solve.

Comment: If you have a vps where you root (which should be the case) then of course you can set up https. It all depends on what web server you use. As it does not sound like you have a lot of experience, I would suggest the use of something like let's encrypt, which will modify your configuration files directly in order to use redirects, hsts and strong ciphers